# How to set Bootstrap menu items from a navbar-nav inverse in the center?

Tags: css, menu, navbar, centering

Hello everyone and thank you for reading this.
I have a default bootstrap navbar that im using , i want the items to be centered and i tryed following methods which didn't work somehow (but seem to work for others) so i must be doing something wrong.

**Option 1 :**

```
nav.nav-center{margin:0;float:none} 
.navbar-inner{ text-align:center}
```

**Option 2 :**

```
.navbar.center .navbar-inner{text-align: center}
.navbar.center .navbar-inner .nav{display:inline-block;float:none}
```

**Option 3 :**

```
 .navbar.center .navbar-inner{text-align: center}
 .navbar-nav {width:100%;text-align:center};
```

> li {float: none;display: inline-block}

so none of the above worked.  I don't understand why.[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fke4x6h9/)    Thank you in advance ! Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have found the reason why it wasn't changing anything, since im using the navbar-inverse and not the default i had to specify that , but the text-align:center doesn't work , i could only get it to work with setting the margin-left to X % for it to be centered which imo is not the best solution but at least is a temporarely one.  Im still open to any help ! Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Thy this one

`.navbar-collapse li a {
    text-align: center;
}`

It is not a good practice to make such specific CSS rules, but this one works for me.

Comment: Im sorry , what i want is not centering them when the menu is collapsed , but when its not collapsed. But i don't dislike it centering it when its collapsed so thank you for that i must say :) I don't understand something , when i do it in the fiddle it works , when doing it on the actual site (doing exactly the same) it doesn't and i think thats the reason previously tryed solutions didn't worked neither. And how would the better practice be in your opinion , what would be the best way of achieving this ?  Thank you for the fast answer !

Comment: I still haven't find out why its not apllying the changes when i put the above answer into the css. In the fiddle it works , not on the actual site so there must be some css interfering with the bootstrap one but i looked and there isn't any other css file that implements or uses **.navbar-collapse** or any nav attributes ... im kind of clueless on where to look as for resolving this ...  Kind regards

Comment: And in the inspect element im seeing navbar**.less** , where is this coming from , i read this : http://lesscss.org/   but i have no idea where its coming from , basically i know what has to be changed but when i change it it doesn't work so either im changing it on the wrong place or there is something else ... Any help would be greatly appreciated !